# Scheduling and Lifetime of boost::future with continuations

Tags: c++, boost, future

I have a question about the scheduling and lifetime of futures which are continuations.

If you create a continuation on a `boost::future` in a future and then the function returns without blocking on the results of the continuation itself will it run the continuation?

As with the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>

auto calculate_foo(int input) {

    auto a = boost::async([input]{
        std::cout << input << std::endl;
        return input * 2;
    });

    auto s = a.share();

    auto b = s.then([](auto t) {
        auto v = t.get();
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(v));
    });

    auto c = s.then([](auto t) {
      auto v = t.get();
      std::cout << v << std::endl;
      boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(v));

    });

    return s;
}

int main() {

    auto z = calculate_foo(1000);

    z.wait();

    return 0;
}
```

So I have a function `calculate_foo` which starts some work. We then create 2 continuations `b` and `c` and deliberately wait sleep in those to ensure that `calculate_foo` returns quickly.

I would have thought that `b` and `c` would be still scheduled since we returned the parent future but this appears to not happen.

Any assistance welcome to correct my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You ask if the continuation will be run when the code doesn't block on its results (calls `get()` or `wait()`). The answer is - "**It depends** on the specified *execution policy*".

The context in which `async()` executes the "continuation" code depends on the *execution policy* specified by the parameter:

```
// Execute on different thread
boost::async(launch::async, []() {...}); 

// Execute inline when result is requested (or wait() call)
boost::async(launch::deferred, []() {...});
```

The same applies to the code passed to `then()` because internally it just calls `async()`.

When no policy parameter is supplied, the default execution policy is `launch::async | launch::deferred` which leaves the library to decide which policy should be used. Usually the deferred option is chosen. Thus, **since the result of `b` and `c` is never requested, the code usually won't be executed at all**.

For example, adding `launch::async` to `c` as below will cause `a` and `c` to be executed (`c` starts executing, requests `a`'s result, so `a` executes as well), but `b` still won't be triggered:

`auto c = s.then(launch::async, [](auto t) {...});`

### NOTE: `std` as alternative to `boost`

Please mind that the `then()` function is ***experimental*** and not compatible with the C++ standard `std::future`. Since C++11, you should prefer using the standard library over `boost` for portability reasons. Boost usually serves as the "playground" before features get incorporated into the standard. You can achieve `then()` like functionality with `std::future` like this:

```
template<typename T, typename Func>
auto chain_to(std::launch policy, std::shared_future<T> f, Func&& second_func) {
    return std::async(policy, [f, second_func = std::forward<Func>(second_func)]() {
       return second_func(f);
    });
}

template<typename T, typename Func>
auto chain_to(std::shared_future<T> f, Func&& second_func) {
    return std::async([f, second_func = std::forward<Func>(second_func)]() {
       return second_func(f);
    });
}

// Use like:
auto b = chain_to(std::launch::async, my_first_shared_future, [](auto f) { ... });
```

This [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/64b7e3n66) demonstrates that using `launch::async` policy your code actually causes all the three lambdas to be executed.